# QQuickWidget and C++ interaction

Tags: c++, qt, qquickwidget

I am experiencing with the new QQuickWidget. How can I interact between the QQuickWidget and C++?

**C++**

```
QQuickWidget *view = new QQuickWidget();
view->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("myqml.qml"));
view->setProperty("test", 0);

myLayout->addWidget(view);
```

**QML**

```
import QtQuick 2.1

Rectangle {
    id: mainWindow
    width: parent.width
    height: parent.height

    Text {
        id: text
        width: mainWindow.width
        font.pixelSize: 20
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        text: test
    }
}
```

`text: test` does not work: `ReferenceError: test is not defined`

How can I give my QML file some properties via C++?

Is it also possible to get the Text object in C++ and update its text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give it a try:

```
view->rootContext()->setContextProperty("test", "some random text");
```

instead of

```
view->setProperty("test", 0);
```

[`setProperty(name, val)`](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qobject.html#setProperty) works if object has the property `name` defined as `Q_PROPERTY`.

It is possible to pass `QObject`-derived object as `view`'s context property:

```
class Controller : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QString m_test;

public:
    explicit Controller(QObject *parent = 0);

    Q_PROPERTY(QString test READ test WRITE setTest NOTIFY testChanged)

    QDate test() const
    {
        return m_test;
    }

signals:

    void testChanged(QString arg);

public slots:

    void setTest(QDate arg)
    {
        if (m_test != arg) {
            m_test = arg;
            emit testChanged(arg);
        }
    }
};
```

---

```
Controller c;
view->rootContext()->setContextProperty("controller", &c);
```

---

```
Text {
        id: text
        width: mainWindow.width
        font.pixelSize: 20
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        text: controller.test
    }
```

> Is it also possible to get the Text object in C++ and update its text?

In general, it doesn't seem to be the [best approach](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HN9mwHWH9DU&list=WL#t=340) -- `c++` code shouldn't be aware of presentation if it follows model-view pattern.

However it is possible as described [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html).

Comment: don't see the reason why `setContextProperty("test", 0)` doesn't work as well as `setContextProperty("test", "some random text")`